# Exporting 3D image from Matlab to u3D or any other 3D format

Tags: matlab, 3d, export

I have a question regarding the exportation of a 3D image made in Matlab to any other 3D format (u3D, collada, Fbx). 
I have a stack of images (ct images) and I used the isosurface method in Matlab in order to obtain the 3D volume rendering.
The code is as follows:

```
p_bone=patch(isosurface(volume_gabbia,0));%create isosurface patch
isonormals(volume_gabbia,p_bone)%compute and set normals
set(p_bone,'FaceColor','m','EdgeColor','none')%set surface props
daspect([1 1 1])                             
view(3), axis vis3d tight, box on, grid on    
camproj perspective                           
camlight, lighting phong, alpha(.2)
```

`volume_gabbia` is a stack of images which contains only the ribcage.
The result is an image (.fig) volume that I can rotate, move, ecc...

Now I need to export this 3D volume in a 3D file (u3D r similar).
I've tried to use the Fig2u3d file (http://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37640-export-figure-to-3d-interactive-pdf) but I get the following error:

> fig2u3d No surfaces found.
>        Preprocessing patch No.1 Undefined function 'ddisp' for input arguments of type 'char'.
>
> Error in u3d_pre_patch>single_patch_preprocessor (line 115)
>       ddisp('Patch: Fixing face color')
>
> Error in u3d_pre_patch (line 70)
>       [v, f, fvx, r] = single_patch_preprocessor(h);
>
> Error in fig2u3d (line 195) [patch_vertices, patch_faces,
>   patch_facevertexcdata, patch_renderers] = u3d_pre_patch(ax);

Does anyone know how can I export a 3D image from Matlab?

Comment: Try exporting as .stl (look at file exchange), it is much better supported. Then convert with meshlab.

Comment: I did it and it worked out perfectly.  I've really appreciated your help

Comment: @Thomas you can post this as an answer I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try exporting as .stl (look at file exchange), it is much better supported. Then convert to u3d with meshlab.

Comment: Well, sorry one last question. Now with your help I've succeeded in exporting the three isosurfaces that I needed. These are in three different stl files. Now in Meshlab I loaded the three meshes all together and I want to export them all in only one collada file but when I do it, Meshlab makes me create one collada file for every mesh and not one collada file with the three meshes. Can you please help me? Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you very very much

Comment: Open the layer panel (Ctrl+L). Right click one of the layers and select "Flatten Visible Layers" - this merges all mesh parts. Then "export as"...

Answer (score 0):

I [unintendedly introduced](https://github.com/johnyf/fig2u3d/commit/b48b16e07abafd663f926a2226868877237a1c75#diff-52fac123fb0ebd0d6828aed6e4a74f49R115) the call to the function `ddisp` during maintenance.
The function `ddisp` is a local convenience wrapper for `disp` that was used to filter debug output globally (in absence of any proper [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-logging) infrastructure in `matlab`).

Fixed as of commit [e15999](https://github.com/johnyf/fig2u3d/commit/e159995ac5ddcd6f000165f2b19011e24882b1b8). Thanks for reporting it.